# Storage Access Framework и выбор SD-карты

Tags: android, storage, android-permissions, sd

Я использую следующий стандартный код для выбора SD-карты для дальнейшей работы с ней с помощью SAF (Storage Access Framework):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
void showDocumentTreeDialog() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_sd_card_title)), REQUEST_CODE_SD_CARD);
}
```

Также вместо `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` я использовала `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, однако в обоих случаях вместо ожидаемого chooser-a я получаю следующее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

в манифесте присутствуют. В чём может быть причина того, что sd-карта не видна?

Comment: Версия Android?

Comment: @Suvitruf, 6.0.1

Comment: Попробуйте без категории

Comment: @woesss, попробовала - то же самое...

Comment: @woesss, хотя нет, то же самое, если без категории и с `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. А если без категории и с `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, то открывается chooser, правда, sd-карты в его списке нет, только "Последние" документы.

Comment: @woesss, а нет, и даже карта памяти нашлась, просто была спрятана в overflow-меню) Спасибо, Ваш комментарий помог! Если оформите как ответ, обязательно приму)

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, это связано с тем, что на [6.0+ перпишены нужно запрашивать в рантайме](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt):

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

То есть, перед тем, как что-то делать, нужно запросить разрешение. Если пользователь предоставит его, то после этого уже что-то делать.

Comment: Добавила код для запроса разрешений, но `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)` возвращает `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. Так что вроде как не в этом дело, получается?..

Comment: Спасибо, но всё-таки дело было в лишней категории Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE))

Comment: @Ksenia занятно. Но хорошо, что всё решилось)